# java graphic library

Tags: java, graphics

i'm trying to develop an interface like Windows Task Manager -> Performance Tab using Java. Can you suggest any Java Graphic Library to ease my development ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about how to generate charts like the processor usage chart in Windows Task Manager / Performance, have a look at for example [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).

Java has a powerful 2D graphics API built-in, see [Trail: 2D Graphics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/index.html) in Sun's Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java2D

Or, for more advanced graphics, you can use OpenGL

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

try swing or awt ;)

Comment: I wanted to ask sth like this :

http://geosoft.no/graphics/index.html

Answer (score 0):

SWT is another option:
http://www.eclipse.org/swt/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by penguru, the [G 2D graphics library](http://geosoft.no/graphics/index.html) could ease the java 2D usage :

> G is a generic graphics library built on top of Java 2D in order to make scene graph oriented 2D graphics available to client applications in a high level, easy to use way.